# Scipy.sparse - lil_matrix multiplication does not work

Tags: python, scipy, sparse-matrix

I tried to generate random markov matrices as `sparse` with `lil_matrix` from `scipy.sparse` package:

```
markov = lil_matrix((n, n), dtype=float)

for i in range(n):
    entries = random.randrange(5, 10 + 1, 1)
    for j in range(entries):
        pos = random.randrange(0, n, 1)
        while markov[pos, i] != 0:
            pos = random.randrange(0, n, 1)
        markov[pos, i] = 1.0 / entries

ones = lil_matrix((n, n), dtype=float)
ones.data[:] = 0.15 * (1.0 / n)

fac = lil_matrix((n, n), dtype=float)
fac.data[:] = (1 - 0.15)

left = markov.multiply(fac) #<- fails!
```

But the last code line failes with:

```
TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable
```

why is that?

Comment: after the following dirty hack `fac.data[:] = (1 - 0.15)` you have destroyed your `lil_matrix`. You've corrupted `ones` in the same way

Comment: @MaxU Do you have any idea how to initialize a `lil_matrix` or `csr_matrix` with the same value (in this case `1-0.15`)?

Comment: do you mean to initialize __ALL__ elements or those that are `!=0`?

Comment: @MaxU all elements

Comment: initializing all elements will explode your sparse matrix into a dense matrix. IMO it doesn't make much sense to use sparse matrices in this case...

Comment: The `data` attribute of a `lil` is an object dtype array of lists, one per row.  Look at `fac.data` right after creating.  For a `csr` matrix, `data` is a numeric array, one value for each nonzero in the matrix.  So `M.data[:]=...` makes some sense with `csr`, but not with `lil`.